# Multiple domain with the same ip and port in apache

Tags: dns, virtualhost, apache, domain-name

I want to bind two different domain in my VPS with the same ip and port, here is my `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost 106.187.96.123:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/roy/sobuhu
    ServerName aaa.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 106.187.96.123:80>
    DocumentRoot /disk1/allen/www
    ServerName bbb.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 106.187.96.123:80>
    DocumentRoot /disk1/allen/www
    ServerName www.bbb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I config the ServerName use syntax like *.bbb.com ? 
so I can access www.bbb.com、bbs.bbb.com with the `DocumentRoot /disk1/allen/www`.

Now I visit bbs.bbb.com, it will turn to `/home/roy/sobuhu`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/roy/sobuhu
    ServerName aaa.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /disk1/allen/www
    ServerName bbb.com
    ServerAlias *.bbb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm new to VirtualHost config. Please could you explain how incoming requests to aaa.com or bbb.com are handled ? Can you actually access aaa.com or bbb.com on your local machine ? If not what needs to be done ? tinkering with your host file ? Does my network admin need to do anything ?

Comment: @van, you'd need to edit the OS's hosts file ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) ) to resolve those domain-names to local IP 127.0.0.1 - so you can use those domain-names locally at least.