# Hosting Multiple Sites On Same Apache Instance (ReviewBoard, MediaWiki)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, mediawiki

We're trying to set up two sites on same Apache instance, although on different ports.

We have a ReviewBoard set up on an Apache in an AWS instance. It runs on 443, and is working fine.

Now, we're trying to set up MediaWiki on same server. I'm assuming safest and fastest way is to set it to  listen on a different port. So, we've set up Apache to listen on 8443, and enabled MediaWiki like so

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:8443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            DocumentRoot /var/www/<domain_name>
```

This is working fine for accessing homepage of wiki.

following are the issues we're facing -

1. This setup requires adding port to the URL. Since https by default uses 443, we need to add :8443 at end of url to access Wiki Page. Ideally, we'd like to do away with the port.
2. MediaWiki Login doesn't work. After login, user is redirected to port 80. If this port is blocked, which is what we want, whole flow is dead in water.
3. We'd like to use same AWS instance, although we're open to setting up another instance of Apache (not sure if it is possible / best practice).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks TyA.

Solved this.

1. [Multiple domain with the same ip and port in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763234/multiple-domain-with-the-same-ip-and-port-in-apache)
2. TyA's solution.
3. Separate AWS or Apache instance not required.

Answer (score 0):

For issue number 2, make sure that you've updated your [$wgServer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) variable to include the not-standard port number like so $wgServer = "https://127.0.0.1:8443";